# Problem with adding line in drawer on the bottom

Tags: flutter, drawer, listtile

I've tried to add one of the lines at the bottom of my drawer but it doesn't work. Here's my drawer code:

```
drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 127,
                child: DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber[400]),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Train Me',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  'Witaj, Kuba',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.grey,
                thickness: 1,
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: Icon(Icons.settings, size: 22),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(text: ' Ustawienia', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                ])),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.grey,
                thickness: 1,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: const Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
                      WidgetSpan(
                        child: Icon(Icons.info_outline, size: 22),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(text: ' About', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                    ])),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

I've tried to solve it with Align and Expanded widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to add a "About" ListTile at the bottom of the drawer using an Align and Expanded widget. However, the problem is that the ListView in your Drawer has a fixed height and is not scrollable, which means that the Expanded widget won't work as expected.

To fix this issue, you can replace the Expanded widget with a SizedBox and set its height to a fixed value that will accommodate your "About" ListTile. Here's the modified code that should work for you:

```dart
drawer: Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 127,
        child: DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber[400]),
          child: const Text(
            'Train Me',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Witaj, Kuba',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      Divider(
        color: Colors.grey,
        thickness: 1,
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Icon(Icons.settings, size: 22),
          ),
          TextSpan(text: ' Ustawienia', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
        ])),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      Divider(
        color: Colors.grey,
        thickness: 1,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 60, // set the height to a fixed value
        child: Align(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
          child: ListTile(
            title: const Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
              WidgetSpan(
                child: Icon(Icons.info_outline, size: 22),
              ),
              TextSpan(text: ' About', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
            ])),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

In the modified code, I replaced the Expanded widget with a SizedBox that has a fixed height of 60. This should give you enough space to accommodate your "About" ListTile at the bottom of the drawer. I also removed the child from the Expanded widget and replaced it with the ListTile wrapped in an Align widget.